# R knitting html with buttons

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to make the knit output of HTML of many graphs , with button option as below?
(normally knitting html makes the graphs one under the other)

[image]

Comment: what about a shiny app?

Comment: You could try using HTML tabs by specifying `{.tabset}` in your section header https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-tabs.html It's not *exactly* what you want, but you could group your images if there are any semantic meaning behind them.

Comment: yes but I can not do this in loops, I have a loop drawing 50 graphs. so I have make button for each of them. how?

Comment: can you attempt to reduce the number of plots by using `ggplot` and `facet_wrap` or changing `par()` so that multiple plots are displayed?

Comment: Looking at your plots, it appears you're wanting to plot distributions for all your variables. You can consider using the `summarytools` package to make a really nice report and visual of all the variable distributions and more information https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools#24-data-frame-summaries-with-dfsummary